# Nuxt/Vuetify - v-autocomplete not displaying the v-menu

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, v-autocomplete

Edit2: I found out the answer to this, you might also miss this one out if you're just starting on vuetify, or that you just directly dive into it and integrate it into an existing project without reading its [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/) like me . Vuetify won't work if it's not inside the application tag or `<v-app>` tag. So make sure if you're using a layout, that you wrap your code inside the `v-app` tag, the stylings may apply, but the functionalities won't work if you did not wrap using the application tag.

**Original Question:**

I can't seem to be able to make the the `v-autocomplete` work in any of my project, I tried it in 2 different projects, one installed using `npm`, and the other installed using the `nuxt-create`. I even copied the code from their demo on their website, but that didn't work too. These are the package version for each project:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
  "core-js": "^3.15.1",
  "nuxt": "^2.15.7",
  "vuetify": "^2.5.5"
},
```

and

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.12.1",
  "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.27",
  "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
  "jest": "^24.1.0",
  "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
  "vue-jest": "^4.0.0-0"
}
```

I can see the `v-menu` and the list in my array when I inspect element but it has a default style of `display: none;`, and because of that, even if I clicked or start typing, the array of supposed autocompletes wouldn't show.

So my question would be, how do I make it to work like how it's supposed to work in the demo on their website?

Edit1: I found out a little quirk about this, It would now work, but only on pages with default layout. So when I set a custom layout, like this one, `layout: 'sidebar-layout',` on the /device page, the `v-autocomplete`'s dropdown would never open, unless I set the `div` class `v-menu` using element inspector in my browser. I haven't yet found out what's causing this, could either be in the layout or the component called into it.

Comment: it might be too obvious, but did you remember to install the packages after you pasted them into package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is silly or not, but the fix for this was to make sure that your code inside your `layout.vue` file is wrapped inside a `<v-app>` tag.

So this was the layout that was causing the issue:

```html
<template>
 <div class="main__container">
   <div class="sidebar__container">
      <Sidebar />
   </div>
   <div class="main__content">
      <Nuxt />
   </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

After comparing to the `vuetify`'s default layout, that one had all of it's code wrapped inside a `<v-app>` tag, (which I clearly missed, since I just started using vuetify and immediately used it on an existing project). So after wrapping my layout with `<v-app>` it now worked:

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <div class="main__container">
      <div class="sidebar__container">
        <Sidebar />
      </div>
      <div class="main__content">
        <Nuxt />
      </div>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe forgot to add the `script` part?

[image]

The following code as in the example [in the docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/#examples), totally works on my side

```html
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row
        align="center"
      >
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-autocomplete
            v-model="values"
            :items="items"
            outlined
            dense
            chips
            small-chips
            label="Outlined"
            multiple
          ></v-autocomplete>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-autocomplete
            v-model="values"
            :items="items"
            dense
            chips
            small-chips
            label="Solo"
            multiple
            solo
          ></v-autocomplete>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-autocomplete
            v-model="value"
            :items="items"
            dense
            filled
            label="Filled"
          ></v-autocomplete>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-card>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      items: ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz'],
      values: ['foo', 'bar'],
      value: null,
    }),
  }
</script>
```

Here is a working [github link](https://github.com/kissu/so-vuetify-autocomplete) if you need a confirmation.
`yarn && yarn dev` and everything should work fine.

Comment: Hey there @kissu, I did make sure to set the array on both of my projects, one, with a dynamic array pulled from an API, and the other static one, I have copied from the script tab of an example from the vuetify website. And both works, I can inspect element the DOM and I can see that they are in fact in the DOM, it's just that the `div` with the class `v-menu` inside the `v-autocomplete` component doesn't display them because of `display: none` property on that class. I can make it display them by editing that part of the CSS, but I don't think that is how it's supposed to work.